# Find the points closest to two lines using least squares method

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition, least-squares

Given are two lines $g(t)=a+bt$ and $h(s)=c+ds$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R^3$. I need to find the points where the two lines are closest using the least squares method. However I am unable to find a solution for this problem.

Intuitively those points are where $g(t)-h(s)$ is as small as possible, but I don't know how to translate this into my understanding of a least squares problem. In my understanding what the least squares method does is it fits a line as close as possible to a set of given points. However given two lines this set of points seems to be infinite and therefore I don't know what that line should be. I think where I am stuck is that my understanding of the least squares method is too specific and limited to fitting straight lines.

Comment: What's wrong with minimizing $\|g(t)-h(s)\|^2$ as a function of $s,t$, using calculus?

Comment: The question specifically asks for a solution using least squares. Plus even if a solution using calculus would be allowed, now I want to know how to do it using least squares.

Comment: Isn't minimizing squared difference of two functions the least squares method itself? In other words, why don't my answer fit? Thanks.

Comment: Echoing @AlexeyBurdin: "least" and "minimizing" are pals, and $\|g(t)-f(s)\|^2$ is "squares".  "Solving the normal equations" is calculus.   Put another way: what do you think "least squares" is, anyway?

Comment: Fine, you're right, the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) agrees with you.

Comment: @kimchilover I used to think this kind of problem was inextricably tied up with Calculus, until I taught Linear Algebra for the first time, and realized there is an entirely Calculus-free way of thinking about it that relies on thinking about the geometry of the parameter space and projecting onto a specific subspace.  See my answer for details. Since the question is tagged linear-algebra I assume that is the method the OP needs to use.

Comment: @mweiss Yes. Translated into Kimchi-speak, you are saying the line  connecting the 2 closest points is perpendicular to both the original lines, which can be seen by using complete-the-squares arguments encoding Pythagoras's theorem, without calculus.  I agree.  This is a non-calculus way of reaching the normal equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, you're looking for a point where $g(t) - h(s)$ is as small as possible. Let's unpack what that means.

If the two lines actually crossed, we would be looking for a point where
$$bt - ds + (a-c) = 0$$
This can be written in the equivalent form as the matrix equation
$$\begin{bmatrix} b & -d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} t \\ s \end{bmatrix} = c - a$$
If we introduce the notation $A = \begin{bmatrix} b & -d \end{bmatrix}$, $\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} t \\ s \end{bmatrix}$, $\vec{b_0} = \begin{bmatrix} c - a \end{bmatrix}$, you want to solve
$$A \vec{x} = \vec{b_0}$$
But this equation doesn't have any solutions, because the lines don't actually cross.  Another way of expressing this fact is that $\vec{b_0}$ is not in $\operatorname{im} A$.

This is where least-squares suddenly kicks in.  Since $\vec{b_0}$ is not in $\operatorname{im} A$, we find the point $\vec{b^*}$ that *is* in $\operatorname{im} A$ and is as close to $\vec{b_0}$ as possible.  This point can be found by projection onto $\operatorname{im} A$:

$$\vec{b^*} = \operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{im} A} \vec{b_0}$$

Then we want to solve the least-squares equation
$$A \vec{x^*} = \operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{im} A}\vec{b_0}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: If I had my $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b & -c & -d\end{bmatrix}$, my $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ t \\ 1 \\ s \end{bmatrix}$ and my $b=0$ and project this $b$ instead, would that be correct also?

Comment: @david No, I don't think so. With that setup the set of vectors $Ax$ would not be a subspace, and in particular would not be $\operatorname{im} A$, so the whole logic of the argument would break down.

Comment: Hmm... I still don’t quite get it then. With that setup the set of vectors $Ax$ would not be a subspace of what?

Comment: @david The set $\left\{A\vec{x} \vert \vec{x} = \left<1, t,  1 ,s \right>, s, t \in \mathbb R \right\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^4$, but it is not a subspace, because it does not contain the zero vector.

Comment: ahh and why does it need to be a subspace? thanks a lot for your clear explanations btw!

Comment: Do you know how to project onto a set that's not a subspace?  If so, great!  But projecting onto a subspace is conceptually simple: you find an orthonormal basis for the subspace, project onto each basis vector, and then sum the components.  If the set is not a subspace, then none of that works -- you don't have a basis to begin with, and it's not closed under sums, so the whole method fails.  1/2

Comment: In addition the usual way we teach least-squares (in a linear algebra course) is that you take the equation $$A\vec{x^*} = \operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{im} A}\vec{b_0}$$ and manipulate it into the so-called "normal equation" $$A^T A \vec{x^*} = A^T \vec{b_0}$$ This relies on the fact that the set you project onto is $\operatorname{im} A$, which it can't be if it's not a subspace.  2/2

Answer (score 0):

$$f(s,t)=(g(t)-h(s))^2$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial t}=2g'(t)(g(t)-h(s))=0\\
\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial s}=-2h'(s)(g(t)-h(s))=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
b(a-c+tb-sd)=0\\
d(a-c+tb-sd)=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
b^2&-bd\\bd&-d^2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
t\\s
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
b(c-a)\\d(c-a)
\end{pmatrix}$$
The linear system has one solution when $\det \begin{pmatrix}
b^2&-bd\\bd&-d^2
\end{pmatrix}=-(b^2d^2-(bd)^2)\ne 0$, i.e. when $b\not\parallel d$.
When $d=xb$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then the system becomes
$$b^2\begin{pmatrix}
1&-x\\x&-x^2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
t\\s
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
b(c-a)\\xb(c-a)
\end{pmatrix}$$
We see that the system is consistent and has solutions
$$t=\frac{b(c-a)}{b^2}+xs$$
for a free variable $s$.
Pluging values for $s,\,t$ back into $f$ we obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M=\pmatrix{b&-d}$. Then
$$
\|(a+bt)-(c+ds)\|^2=\left\|M\pmatrix{t\\ s}-(c-a)\right\|^2.
$$
Therefore, the least-norm least-square solution to the minimisation problem is given by
\begin{aligned}
\pmatrix{t\\ s}
&=M^+(c-a)\\
&=\begin{cases}
(M^TM)^{-1}M^T(c-a)&\text{if }\operatorname{rank}(M)=2,\\
\frac{1}{\operatorname{tr}(M^TM)}M^T(c-a)&\text{if }\operatorname{rank}(M)=1,\\
0&\text{if }M=0.\\
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}